# adding a second javascript function is stopping the first from working, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a page that includes two different features:

one) a button that cycles through various feelings on hover, the same functionality as google's "i'm feeling lucky button"

two) a word cloud that populates automatically on page load

for some reason, the button functionality stops working when i add the word cloud functionality. i don't see any variables repeating, so i'm not sure as to why. can someone please help? here is my code:

```js
// Interval and words for placing words randomly
var interval = 100; // Interval between word placements (in milliseconds)

var words = [
  'JavaScript',
  'Angular',
  'ReactJS',
  'Three.js',
  'Moment',
  'Redux',
  'Chart.js',
  'Ember',
  'BackboneJS',
  'Underscore',
  'Reveal.js',
  'Babel',
  'Modernizr',
  'CoffeeScript',
  'TypeScript',
  'Gulp',
  'NodeJS',
  'Select2',
  'Bower',
  'NPM',
  'Express',
  'Pdf.js',
  'Full Page.js',
  'Foundation',
  'Bootstrap',
  'Mocha',
  'Jasmine',
  'D3.js',
  'Mustache.js',
  'Handlebars',
  'jQuery Validation',
  'Lodash',
  'RequireJS',
  'IntroJS',
  'Typeahead.js',
  'Scrollr',
  'MooTools',
  'Prototype',
  'YUI',
  'Dojo',
  'Raphael',
  'Knockout'
];

// Get the width and height of the viewport
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

// Function to place words at random positions
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {
    var word = document.createElement('span');
    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    // Randomly position the word within the viewport
    word.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * height) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(word);
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);

$("button").hover(function(){
  var self = this;
  var pos = -(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) * 55
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(self).find("ul").css("margin-top", pos + "px");
  }, 500);
}, function(){
  $(this).find("ul").css("margin-top", "0px");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
} */

button {
  margin: 10% auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  border: #DCDCDC 1px solid;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #F1F1F1);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #F1F1F1);
}

button:hover {
  border-color: darken(#DCDCDC, 5%);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #F1F1F1);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #F1F1F1);
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 1px;
  outline: none !important;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 1px #08c solid;
}

button ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
}

button ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 1em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top"></div>

<button>
  <ul>
    <li>I'm Feeling Lucky</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Alone</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Absence</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Void</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Deficit</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Lack</li>
  </ul>  
</button>
```

any help as to how i would be able to include both features here without one interfering with the other would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: If the added function was not valid javascript, that could prevent the valid function from executing.

Comment: Please see [ask], then reduce your code to just what's needed to show the problem. There's a huge amount of irrelevant stuff up there, which makes our conversation much more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine.  You just can't hover over the button because you've covered the button with `<span>` elements.

Without completely re-implementing your word cloud, one possible approach is to give the `<button>` a `z-index` value in the CSS:

```
z-index: 2;
```

For example:

```js
// Interval and words for placing words randomly
var interval = 100; // Interval between word placements (in milliseconds)

var words = [
  'JavaScript',
  'Angular',
  'ReactJS',
  'Three.js',
  'Moment',
  'Redux',
  'Chart.js',
  'Ember',
  'BackboneJS',
  'Underscore',
  'Reveal.js',
  'Babel',
  'Modernizr',
  'CoffeeScript',
  'TypeScript',
  'Gulp',
  'NodeJS',
  'Select2',
  'Bower',
  'NPM',
  'Express',
  'Pdf.js',
  'Full Page.js',
  'Foundation',
  'Bootstrap',
  'Mocha',
  'Jasmine',
  'D3.js',
  'Mustache.js',
  'Handlebars',
  'jQuery Validation',
  'Lodash',
  'RequireJS',
  'IntroJS',
  'Typeahead.js',
  'Scrollr',
  'MooTools',
  'Prototype',
  'YUI',
  'Dojo',
  'Raphael',
  'Knockout'
];

// Get the width and height of the viewport
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

// Function to place words at random positions
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {
    var word = document.createElement('span');
    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    // Randomly position the word within the viewport
    word.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * height) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(word);
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);

$("button").hover(function(){
  var self = this;
  var pos = -(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) * 55
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(self).find("ul").css("margin-top", pos + "px");
  }, 500);
}, function(){
  $(this).find("ul").css("margin-top", "0px");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
} */

button {
  margin: 10% auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  border: #DCDCDC 1px solid;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #F1F1F1);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #F1F1F1);
  z-index: 2;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: darken(#DCDCDC, 5%);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #F1F1F1);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #F1F1F1);
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 1px;
  outline: none !important;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 1px #08c solid;
}

button ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin-top .45s ease-in-out;
}

button ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 1em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top"></div>

<button>
  <ul>
    <li>I'm Feeling Lucky</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Alone</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Absence</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Void</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Deficit</li>
    <li>I'm Feeling Lack</li>
  </ul>  
</button>
```